# Cómo normalizar un número telefónico en Android

Tags: java, android

estoy desarrollando una app que se encarga de bloquear llamadas indeseadas y de spam. El problema se produce devido a que al recibir la llamada entrante desde la app en Android, el formato del número telefónico difiere del ingresado por el usuario en la lista de contactos.

Ejemplo:

- Número ingresado por el usuario en la lista de contactos: **155073607**
- Número telefónico recibido de la llamada entrante: **2615073607** (código de área local)+(número telefónico sin 15).
- Aclaración: (En argentina para llamar a números celulares en el caso de mi provincia Mendoza, en algunos casos es obligatorio anteponer el código de área de la provincia '261', el cual representa el 15 y luego se coloca el número sin el primer 15 que suelen tener todos los números celulares).
  El `15` es el prefijo que se usa para llamar de un teléfono fijo a un celular, pero también se permite marcarlo desde un celular a otro. En resumen, el número podría estar anotado de cualquiera de las siguientes formas:

  ```
  +54 261 15 5073607    MCC LAC 15 número
  +54 261 5073607       MCC LAC    número
  261 15 5073607            LAC 15 número
  261 5073607               LAC    número
  15 5073607                    15 número
  5073607                          número
  ```

  - Además, el LAC puede tener 2, 3 o 4 dígitos, pero siempre LAC+número son 8 dígitos.

A continuación describo las formas en que leo la lista de contacto para obtener los números télefonicos que el usuario puede escoger para bloquear posteriormente la llamada entrante:

**Acceso a la lista de contactos**:

```
return new CursorLoader(
getActivity(),   // Parent activity context
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, // Table to query
new String[]{
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,

},     // Projection to return
null,
null,            // No selection arguments
null             // Default sort order

...
String phoneNumber = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(loader.getId() == LOAD_CONTACTS_CURSOR ? ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER : CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)););
```

**Acceso a la llamada entrante:**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
      final Strng incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER));
}}
```

> Edit: Por sugerencia de un usuario el código de área local es denominado LAC, procedi a obtener dicho código pero el resultado fue incorrecto:

```
final TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
final GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) telephony.getCellLocation();
location.getLac();
//Devuelve LAC: 16227 en vez de 261
```

En conclusión, ¿existe alguna posibilidad de averiguar el código de área local de modo de poder "matchear" ambos números telefónicos?.

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Probablemente te convenga aclarar cómo es el tema con el `15` en Argentina, para que alguien de otro país pueda entender la diferencia.

Comment: Agregado, gracias por tu sugerencia.

Comment: Edité agregando más información. No puse lo del `9` antes del código de área. No sé si vas a considerarlo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, por lo que veo LAC es a lo que se denomina código de área local?. Voy a buscar más información para ver si puedo encontrar alguna solución apartir de ese término.

Comment: Publicado también en http://stackoverflow.com/q/43083260/5290909